# vscode-jest: codelens appear only once

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs, create-react-app, codelens

I am using Jest in my CRA + Typescript application (ejected). Recently I have installed the vscode-jest extension. When I first open vscode and go to a test file, I can see there are codelens "Debug" next to each of my test (next to the "it" keep word).

[image]

Clicking on "Debug" get the specific test running (which is really cool and handy). But then if I close this file and reopen it, codelens disappear after the first run and I cannot seem to get them reappear for subsequent run.

The only way is to close and reopen Vscode.

Is this a known bug? or am I forgetting something? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should file an issue against whatever extension is providing those code lenses

Comment: I noticed it doesn't show if the test passes or when jest stopped because it failed to many times. I had to reload window to get it to work as described here: this:https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to VS Code settings.json:

```json
"jest.debugCodeLens.showWhenTestStateIn": [
  "fail",
  "unknown",
  "pass"
],
```